# chain rule of two related functions

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose I have the functions $f(x,y)=xy-y$ and $g(u,v)=f(u,uv)$ and I want to calculate dg(a,b) two ways (1) explicitly and (2) using chain rule

My attempt:
for (1) it seems easy enough just plug x=u and y=uv then,
$g(u,v)=f(u,uv)=u^2v-uv$ and 
$\nabla g =(2uv-v,u^2-u)$ and plug points (a,b) for (u,v)

for (2) I know that,
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(1)+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(v)$ but how do I proceed from here?  I should get the same answer as part (1) no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\text{let } x & = u
\qquad \therefore 
\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} = 1, \quad \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = 0
\\[2ex]
\text{let }  y &= uv
\qquad \therefore 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial u} = v , \quad \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = u
\\[2ex]
g(u, v) & = g(x, y/x) = f(x,y) = xy-y
\\[2ex]
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & = y \qquad\qquad= uv
\\[2ex]
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} & = x-1 \qquad = u-1
\end{align}$$

Put them together to obtain $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
\\[2ex]
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial v} =  = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$$